# Prove that $R/I$ is free if and only if $I=0.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Prove that $R/I$ is free if and only if $I=0.$

```
Is my following proof OK?
```

Assume $R/I$ is a free $R$-module. Then $\mathrm{Ann}(R/I)=0.$ That means $\{x \in R|x(r+I)=xr+I=0+I\},$ for all $r \in R.$ So $xr \in I$ for all $r \in R.$ So $x \in I.$ But $xr=0$ for all $r \in R.$ So $x=0.$ Since $x$ was arbitrary, $I=0.$

Assume $I=0.$ Then $\mathrm{Ann}(R/I)=\mathrm{Ann}(R)=0.$ So the zero element itself annihilates $R.$ Since the empty set is trivially a basis for $R/I, R/I$ is free.

Comment: What is R (a ring, a commutative one, with unit...??), what is I (an ideal...?) ? Things must be explained more carefully

Comment: Superficially it doesn't look right, though maybe your idea is right and you're just not expressing it well.  You seem to be assuming that $\mathrm{Ann}(R/I) = 0$ means everything in $R$ annihilates everything else, and this leads you to prove that an arbitrary element of $R$ is zero?  Probably not what you meant.  You need to say what things are and where things live.  If $x$ is arbitrary you need to introduce it by saying "let $x$ be an arbitrary element of ..." and so on.

Comment: @Timbuc Yes, $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ is an ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea for the first implication is just fine: a free module is always faithful, but $R/I$ has annihilator $I$, so if it is free, $I=\{0\}$. Good job!

> Since the empty set is trivially a basis for $R/I$ , $R/I$ is free.

This isn't true, and doesn't follow any of the reasoning about the annihilator that you started with. The empty set is never a basis for a nonzero $R$ module. The empty set can only "span" $\{0\}$ in the sense that it is the smallest submodule containing the empty set.

Worrying about annihilators in that direction is off track anyhow. Just note that when $I=\{0\}$, $R/I\cong R$ which is free, so $R/I$ is free as well.

Comment: Dear @rschwieb, I suppose that in the question the ideal $I$ is one-sided (say, left) and $R/I$ is a left $R$-module. Then $\text{Ann}_R(R/I)\subseteq I$, but I can't see why they are equal.

Comment: ·@user26857 In that case they would not be equal. Fortunately that is not the situation the poster outlined:  `@Timbuc Yes, $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ is an ideal. – Anonymous Mar 1 '15 at 17:43`